# How to align validation text on right side of textbox in knockout js?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In my application I am having one textbox as follows

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
   <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.createClassModelView.classTitle" maxlength="50" title="Class title" placeholder="Ex. 'Ph.D. in Mechanical Engineering'" class="width-100" />
   </span>
</div>
```

In my js file I am applying validation as follows

```
classTitle: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true,
            minLength: 5,

            maxLength: 50,           
            pattern: {
                message: 'Class name should only contain alphabet and numbers.',
                params: '^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$',                
            }

        }),
```

The above validation works fine. It shows the message 'This field is required.'. But this message is shown by default just below textbox. I want to show it on right side of textbox. How should I do it? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using default configuration and  knockout validation create span just after field to show default error message. instead of this you can use validationMessage binding to show error message wherever you want.

binding:-

```
 <span data-bind="validationMessage:classTitle "></span>
```

Stop insertion of default error message by setting  insertMessages configuration to false.

```
 ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: false
 });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YVQ6q/1/)